# How to get scope and roles in Oauth2/2.1 spring boot resource server?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, oauth2resourceserver, oauth-2.1

How to get scope and roles in Oauth2/2.1 spring boot resource server?

```
Authentication authentication = getAuthentication();
System.out.println(authentication.getAuthorities());
```

`Authorities` returns only scope.

Here is my token `introspect`

```
{
    "active": true,
    "sub": "0f370b1e-e3a9-4ee3-a8a3-21bbb3437c16",
    "aud": [
        "1"
    ],
    "nbf": 1679019352,
    "scope": "read",
    "roles": [
        "user"
    ],
    "iss": "http://3.6.239.198:9000",
    "exp": 1679022352,
    "iat": 1679019352,
    "client_id": "1",
    "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

How to retrieve `role` in the resource server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created `CustomAuthenticationConverter` to replace `scope` with `roles`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2ResourceServerSecurityConfiguration {
    
    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}")
    private String authServerBaseUrl;
    
    interface Jwt2AuthoritiesConverter extends Converter<Jwt, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>> {
    }

    List<String> publicApis = List.of("/login", "/rest/**", "/token", 
             "/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/vendor/**", "/favicon.ico");
     
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {    
        http.anonymous().disable();       
        http.cors().and().authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .requestMatchers(publicApis.stream()
                        .map(AntPathRequestMatcher::new)
                        .toArray(RequestMatcher[]::new)).permitAll()
            
                .anyRequest().authenticated()).csrf().disable();
            
        http.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
                .jwt(jwt -> jwt
                        .jwtAuthenticationConverter(new CustomAuthenticationConverter())
                    )
                );
    
              
        return http.build();
    }
  
    static class CustomAuthenticationConverter implements Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> {
        public AbstractAuthenticationToken convert(Jwt jwt) {
            Collection<String> authorities = jwt.getClaimAsStringList("roles");
            Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = authorities.stream()
                    .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            return new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, grantedAuthorities);
        }
    }
}
```

To Get roles:

```
Authentication authentication = getAuthentication();
authentication.getAuthorities()
```

Refer :-

Authorization server -> https://github.com/m-thirumal/oauth-authorization-server/

Resource server -> https://github.com/m-thirumal/oauth-resource-server
https://github.com/m-thirumal/oauth-resource-server

Answer (score 0):

You provide with an Authentication converter when configuring the resource-server in your `SecurityFilterChain`:
`http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwtAuthenticationConverter(...)`

Many samples on in the tutorials I wrote: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials